# R: Interpolate a data.table when x's are the names of columns and y's the rows

Tags: r, performance, data.table

Let me exemplify:

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table( value = c(1.3,2.1,2.7), '1' = c(0.4,0.3,0.5), '2' = c(1.1,1.3,1.7) , '3' = c(2.1,2.4,2.6) )

> A
   value   1   2   3
1:   1.3 0.4 1.1 2.1
2:   2.1 0.3 1.3 2.4
3:   2.7 0.5 1.7 2.6
```

I would like to use x = 1,2,3 and y being each row to interpolate the number in the columns "value".

So, for the first row, x = 1,2,3 and y = 0.4, 1.1, 2.1. The value that should be interpolated is x0 = 1.3. And so on for the next rows. I came up with the following function to apply it using a data.table by rows:

```
## Function to Interpolate
interpol <- function(dt){
  # Define X
  x <- c(1,2,3)
  # Grab each row of the data.table
  y <- as.numeric(dt[,c('1','2','3'), with = F])
  # Interpolate and get the value of Y
  approx(x,y,dt[,'value', with = F])$y
}

# Apply by row
A[, interpol(.SD), by = 1:nrow(A)]
```

The problem is that this seems to be extremely slow for a data.table of a few million rows. What would be the best way to optimize this?

## Side Note

Originally, my problem was as follows:

I had to interpolate the same A using a different table B:

```
A2 <- data.table(name = LETTERS[1:3], value = c(1.3,2.1,2.7))
B2 <- data.table(name = LETTERS[1:3], '1' = c(0.4,0.3,0.5), '2' = c(1.1,1.3,1.7) , '3' = c(2.1,2.4,2.6) )

> A2
   name value
1:    A   1.3
2:    B   2.1
3:    C   2.7

> B2
   name   1   2   3
1:    A 0.4 1.1 2.1
2:    B 0.3 1.3 2.4
3:    C 0.5 1.7 2.6
```

I decided to merge these two data.tables to obtain the one above because i believed it would be easier. But maybe for it to run faster it might be better to have them as separate data.tables?

Comment: You can do `melt(A[, id := .I], id=c("id", "value"))[, variable := as.numeric(variable)][, approx(variable, value.1, value[1])$y, by=id]` but I don't really expect that's going to be faster.

Comment: @Frank i like this approach. I'm not sure if is much faster but I think it'll do. One note, I had to do first as.character before as.numeric because the column names were taken as a factor. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Frank actually, this approach is significantly faster. It seems to work great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd suggest storing the `B2` data in long format:

```
dat = melt(B2, id="name", value.name = "v")
dat[, variable := as.numeric(as.character(variable))]

   name variable   v
1:    A        1 0.4
2:    B        1 0.3
3:    C        1 0.5
4:    A        2 1.1
5:    B        2 1.3
6:    C        2 1.7
7:    A        3 2.1
8:    B        3 2.4
9:    C        3 2.6
```

From here, you can join on `A2` to interpolate by group:

```
dat[A2, on=.(name), approx(variable, v, value)$y, by=.EACHI]

   name   V1
1:    A 0.61
2:    B 1.41
3:    C 2.33
```